# The module Node Embed does not work for a custom user role

Tags: nodes, users

I am trying to use the Node Embed module with WYSIWYG editor in Drupal 7 to embed a node. I can do this as an Admin but cannot do it as a custom user role. It says Access Denied when I go to the WYSIWYG editor and the Node Embed plugin. I did check for the permissions for WYSIWYG profiles and also text formats. The custom role has permissions to use/access both. Any thoughts on this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Module Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1476024) for both CKEditor Integration and WYSIWYG Integration it says:

"Enable the default view 'ckeditor-node-embed' (if its not already enabled). This view provides the content of the 7plugin dialog box."

The access to this view is "Permission | Administer Content"

If your custom roles do not have this permission it won't work.

I altered the access to be by Role and selected roles I wanted to be able to use Node Embed and it then worked.